# AngularJs: tooltip on mouse hover to single value of dropdown using ng-options

Tags: angularjs, select, tooltip, ng-options

I am using ng-options for dropdown using 'select' tag.
I have to select only one option from drop down at a time.
While selecting option from drop down I have to show tooltip when I am hovering mouse on particular option.
I am able to show all the values in dropdown but not able to show the tooltip.

Could anyone please tell me how to show tooltip for ng-options?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to create a custom select box for the same. No other element can be associated with the `<option>` tag (Generated by ng-options). And so you cannot introduce tooltip description.
You want me to help you with the code?

Comment: Yes please. Could u please elaborate more on custom select box (I am new to Angular Js)

Comment: Please the codepen http://codepen.io/chiragshah_mb/pen/WxNeZE?editors=1111 

However the select box & tooltip CSS change be changed as desired. You will be able to access the selected option in $scope.selected from there on.

Comment: Thank you Chirag for quick reply!